# Pass data from Firebase from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass a CategoryID from Firebase from one fragment to another 
using an ImageView Click but my app crashes when an ImageView is clicked.

Here is my code;

**MenuFragment.java**

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder> adapter;

viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

                   CarListFragment cfragment= new CarListFragment ();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("CategoryID",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    cfragment.setArguments(bundle);

                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_main, cfragment, cfragment.getTag())
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                }
            });
```

**CarListFragment.java**

```
String CategoryID="";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_list, container, false);


    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        CategoryID=getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryID");
    }


    if(!CategoryID.isEmpty()&& CategoryID!=null){
        loadCarList(CategoryID);
    }


    return v;
}
```

**Logcat**

[image]

Comment: Please post logs as text not images

Answer (score 3):

Use `bundle`because it has the data

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    CategoryID = bundle.getString("CategoryID");
    //           ^^^^^^
}
```

instead of

```
CategoryID=getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryID");
```

because `getActivity().getIntent()` will give you an `Intent` object which was previously used to start your activity

Comment: @FionaMuthoni i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
    CarListFragment cfragment= new CarListFragment ();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("CategoryID", adapter.getRef(position));
                    cfragment.setArguments(bundle);

                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_main, cfragment, cfragment.getTag())
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
```

get String:

```
    String str = getArguments().getString("my_string");
```

Comment: it's just an example of use

Comment: I can change if it's more convenient for you

Comment: Yes, please do.

Comment: Ready. Check, please